# Using strings to merge data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I'm trying to randomly assign some subjects to a set of given data frames (they already have some subjects assigned).

Suppose I have generated

```
set.seed(5)
no_bin <- sample(c("H1","H2","M1","M2"), 7, replace = TRUE)
 vect_groups <- paste0("Group", no_bin)
```

Then I have a string vector
`"GroupH2" "GroupM1" "GroupH1" "GroupM1" "GroupM1" "GroupH1" "GroupH1"`
and I would like to assign the first row of data frame Subjects to Group H2, the second row of data frame subjects to Group M1...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow; could you please provide and example of your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need `split` like below

```
> split(Subjects, vect_groups)
$GroupH1
  subject
3       3
6       6
7       7

$GroupH2
  subject
1       1

$GroupM1
  subject
2       2
4       4
5       5
```

**Dummy Data**

```
Subjects <- data.frame(subject = seq_along(vect_groups))
```